# Формат в миллисекундах в плеере

Tags: javascript, jquery

в плеере используется вывод времени проигрывания трека:

```
music.onloadeddata = function () {
    seekbar.max = music.duration
    var ds = parseInt(music.duration % 60)
    var dm = parseInt((music.duration / 60) % 60)
    duration.innerHTML = dm + ':' + ds
}
music.ontimeupdate = function () { seekbar.value = music.currentTime }
handleSeekBar = function () { music.currentTime = seekbar.value }
music.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    var cs = parseInt(music.currentTime % 60)
    var cm = parseInt((music.currentTime / 60) % 60)
    currentTime.innerHTML = cm + ':' + cs
}, false)
```

Время показывает корректно, но не так, как привыкли юзеры, вместо 0:07, например - показывается 0:7, однако 0:14 показывается корректно.
Вопрос - как добавить 0 для одиночных цифр.

Comment: А в чём проблема превратить число в строку, проверить длину, если длина меньше 2 символов, добавить ноль.

Comment: Вот так https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Comment: Функцию **parseInt()** применяют для вытягивания числа из строки, а для округления больше подходит **Math.floor()**.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много, а можно так

```js
var seven = '7';
var one = '1';

console.log(seven.padStart(2, '0')+ ':' + one.padStart(2, '0'));

var eleven = '11';
var ten = '10';

console.log(eleven.padStart(2, '0')+ ':' + ten.padStart(2, '0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-нибудь, в будущем понадобится:

```
currentTime.innerHTML = `${cm}:${(''+cs).padStart(2, '0')}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ds = Math.floor(music.duration % 60);
ds = ds < 10 ? '0' + ds : ds;
```